# How to align the middle of a View to the bottom of other view in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, layout

So basically I need to come up with a layout that aligns the middle of a View to the bottom of other View in SwiftUI.
To make it more clear, all I need is something like this:

[image]

I guess the equivalent in a UIKit world would be:

```
redView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: whiteView.centerYAnchor)
```

Ive tried setting both in a `ZStack` and offsetting the white View but it won't work on all screen sizes for obvious reasons.

Any tips?

Comment: Show us what you have tried. Also, the height of your white view is fixed or dynamic?

Comment: Size of white view is dynamic as in it takes as much space as the content within that stack occupies (just a label and an image). Regarding what I tried, like I said on the post, Ive tried setting both Views within a ZStack and using .offset(y: 50) for example to bring the red view down but that is obviously wrong as that would maybe work for a specific device but won't on others. Ive also messed with GeometryReaders to get the precise height of the red view but I wasn't really able to accomplish much, sadly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.aligmentGuide` (which is a tricky beast, I recommend [this explanation](https://swiftui-lab.com/alignment-guides/))

Here is your solution, its independent of the child view sizes:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) { // subviews generally aligned at bottom
            redView
            whiteView
                // center of this subview aligned to .bottom
                .alignmentGuide(VerticalAlignment.bottom, 
                                computeValue: { d in d[VerticalAlignment.center] }) 
        }
        .padding()
    }
    
    var redView: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Red View")
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .frame(height: 200)
        .background(Color.red)
        .cornerRadius(20)
    }
    
    var whiteView: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("White View")
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .frame(width: 250, height: 100)
        .background(Color.white)
        .cornerRadius(20)
        .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20).stroke())
    }
    
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much! Ill read on custom alignment guides now as Ive never used them before.

Comment: Would you by any chance have any idea how to make the height of the redView dynamic and make it size itself depending on the contents / size of the whiteView? Ensuring the center of the whiteView is still always the bottom of the redView, of course.

Comment: You might have to create your own `Layout` for this. I made a test, see my second answer.

Answer (score 2):

Based on OPs request in comment, this is a solution making use of a custom `Layout`.
The `HalfOverlayLayout` takes two subview and places the second half height over the first. The size of the first subview is flexible. As this is my first `Layout` I'm not sure if I covered all possible size variants, but it should be a start.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        HalfOverlayLayout {
            redView
            whiteView
        }
        .padding()
    }
    
    
    var redView: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(0..<20) { _ in
                Text("Red View")
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(Color.red)
        .cornerRadius(20)
    }
    
    var whiteView: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("White View")
        }
        .frame(width: 200, height: 150)
        .background(Color.white)
        .cornerRadius(20)
        .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20).stroke())
    }
    
}



struct HalfOverlayLayout: Layout {
    
    func sizeThatFits(proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout ()) -> CGSize {

        let heightContent = subviews.first?.sizeThatFits(.unspecified).height ?? 0
        let heightFooter = subviews.last?.sizeThatFits(.unspecified).height ?? 0
        let totalHeight = heightContent + heightFooter / 2
        
        let maxsizes = subviews.map { $0.sizeThatFits(.infinity) }
        var totalWidth = maxsizes.max {$0.width < $1.width}?.width ?? 0
        if let proposedWidth = proposal.width {
            if totalWidth > proposedWidth { totalWidth = proposedWidth }
        }
        return CGSize(width: totalWidth, height: totalHeight)
    }

    
    func placeSubviews(in bounds: CGRect, proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout ()) {

        let heightFooter = subviews.last?.sizeThatFits(.unspecified).height ?? 0
        let maxHeightContent = bounds.height - heightFooter / 2

        var pt = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.minY)
        if let first = subviews.first {
            var totalWidth = first.sizeThatFits(.infinity).width
            if let proposedWidth = proposal.width {
                if totalWidth > proposedWidth { totalWidth = proposedWidth }
            }
            first.place(at: pt, anchor: .top, proposal: .init(width: totalWidth, height: maxHeightContent))
        }

        pt = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.maxY)
        if let last = subviews.last {
            last.place(at: pt, anchor: .bottom, proposal: .unspecified)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so so much Chris, there's so much learning I need to do on the new Layout protocol as well as stuff such as SwiftUI custom alignments . Sadly I still need to support iOS 13 (or probably 14 and above sometime soon) so I can't take advantage of the new Layout protocol for this, sadly. Regardless, this comes in super handy to kickstart my learning path on the new Layout protocol. Again, can't thank you enough for both solutions!

Comment: This seems like a clear example of something where UIKit would handle this with a single line (redView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: whiteView.centerYAnchor) while SwiftUI requires a much more complex approach. Usually it's the other way around hah. Anyway, huge thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
        ZStack {
        Rectangle()
            .frame(width: 300, height: 400)
            .overlay(
                GeometryReader { proxy in
                    
                    let offsetY = proxy.frame(in: .named("back")).midY
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(Color.red)
                        .offset(y: offsetY)
                }
                    .frame(width: 150, height: 140)
                , alignment: .center)
    }
    .coordinateSpace(name: "back")
```

Bascially the idea is to use coordinateSpace to get the frame of the bottom Rectangle and use geometryreader to get the offset needed by comparing the frame of top rectangle with the bottom one. Since we are using overlay and it is already aligned to the center horizontally, we just need to offset y to get the effect you want.

Comment: Yeey this does achieve the desired effect as well, thank you! I think I'll use the custom alignment way the other user suggested though to avoid using GeometryReader as Apple suggests. But thank yo so much!